# Django Conditional login redirect

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-authentication

This is my middleware which is continuously redirecting.
How can i give conditional redirecting in my middleware? and instead of path name how can i get `path_name`.

middleware.py

```
class PermissionRequiredMiddleware:
   def __init__(self, get_response):
       self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
       response = self.get_response(request)
       return response

   def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

       assert hasattr(request, 'user')
       path = request.path_info

       if request.user.is_authenticated:
           if request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 1 :
               return redirect('superadmin_dashboard')
           elif request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 2 :
               return redirect('admin_dashboard')
           elif request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 3 :
               return redirect('admin_dashboard')
           elif request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 4 :
               return redirect('admin_dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing continuously redirection because, this middleware is getting called for every request you are making, meaning it is recursively itself calling. So you need to put some conditions in the middleware to prevent that.

I think you can try like this:

```
    # lets say your url has name `login_url`
    # ie. (path('/login', name='login_url')

    login_url_name = 'login_url'
    current_url = resolve(request.path_info).view_name
    if request.method == "POST" and current_url == login_url_name:
        if request.user.pk:  # making sure a valid user has logged in. request always has user, but when its not logged in, its AnonymousUser object
            if request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 1 :
                 return redirect('superadmin_dashboard')
            elif request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 2 :
                 return redirect('admin_dashboard')
            elif request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 3 :
                 return redirect('admin_dashboard')
            elif request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 4 :
                 return redirect('admin_dashboard')
    return self.get_response(request)
```

Comment: It is giving error - `current_url = resolve(self.request.path_info).view_name
AttributeError: 'PermissionRequiredMiddleware' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: Now i have remove self then it is giving error - `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
`

Comment: can you share the stacktrace please?